# How to Optimze the below query in MS Access

Tags: sql, ms-access

I wrote a query to find avg distance to a dealer month wise, the query is working pretty fast in SQL, but the same query is taking like infinite time in MS Access. What can i do to Optimize the Query.

```
SELECT su.Buy_PDN
    ,avg(INT (Sqr((69.1 * (Z3.Latitude - Z4.LATITUDE)) * (69.1 * (Z3.Latitude - Z4.LATITUDE)) + (53 * (Z3.Longitude - Z4.Longitude)) * (53 * (Z3.Longitude - Z4.Longitude)))))
FROM (
    (
        (
            (
                tbl1 su INNER JOIN tbl2 AS z1 ON z1.Primary_dlr_num = SU.Sell_PDn
                ) INNER JOIN tblZipCodes AS Z3 ON z1.DlrZip = z3.Zip_Code
            ) INNER JOIN tbl2 AS z2 ON z2.Primary_dlr_num = SU.buy_PDn
        ) INNER JOIN tblZipCodes AS Z4 ON z2.DlrZip = z4.Zip_Code
    )
WHERE su.YEAR = 2016
    AND su.TRANSACTION = 'S'
    AND month = 9
GROUP BY su.Buy_PDN
```

Here i am having transaction which have two pdn, these two pdn have there zip code in tbl2 and in turn tblZipCode is having latitude and longitude for each zip. So this query will find all distinct BuyPDN and find the average distance of all SELLPDN from it in this month.

But it is taking more than 40 minutes to execute the query. How can it be optimized. I tried removing avg part but still query was taking long time which made me come to conclusion that join is taking long time.

Comment: Please clarify: it works fast in MS SQL or where? Tables in Access are linked or local? If linked, what is remote database? First of all check if you have indexes on all columns used in joins and WHERE clause

Comment: In Sql Server. Tables are not linked, they are local. The application is very old so we are not having any primary keys.

Comment: Why not passthrough?

Comment: Add indexes or use linked tables to MS SQL or, better, passthrough to SQL server

Comment: *"The application is very old so we are not having any primary keys."* - I'm pretty sure the concept of primary keys predates MS-Access. :) -- Proper keys and indexes should speed up the query substantially.

Answer (score 0):

Create a field for `distance` in `tbl1`. It can be Calculated Field on Access 2010+ or a field re-calculated through a script on each `buy_PDn` and `Sell_PDn` update. Then the cost of calculation would be spread evenly over table updates and reporting would have all the data ready.